# django cache key belong to which views?

Tags: django, caching, key

I have Django 1.4 cache enabled with Redis as backend.I would like to know which view belongs to my cache key?

:1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page.mysite.GET.077b0d695a2095e154185234de17ad3350.d669abb4a2a0575f43321342f66b.fr

I know it is a template:

```
In [2]: r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=1)
In [3]: dd = r.get('':1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page.mysite.GET.077b0d695a2095e154185234de17ad3350.d669abb4a2a0575f43321342f66b.fr'')
In [6]: obj = cPickle.loads(dd)
In [7]: obj
Out[7]: <django.template.response.TemplateResponse object at 0x2a47050>
```

Is there a way to render this template to see what's inside also?

I tried

```
obj.render()
print(obj.content)
```

but i got some strange characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the Gzip middleware.

Either remove it or use the gzip module do unpack the content.